# How to see com1 communication in Ubuntu 20.04 like in window Hyperterminal

Tags: 20.04

In Windows I can use Window HypterTerminal message sent from COM1. In that I can mention **baudrate, Data bits, parity,stop bits,flow control** and then able to see message sent by external device in the hyper terminal in my windows computer.
[image]
I would like to do be able to see same in my ubuntu system. Is there any command or tool that I can use where I can set these values and see the COM1 messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start using serial ports you have to put your user into *dialout* group by

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

There are many serial port terminal applications in Ubuntu repository. I prefer [CuteCom](https://gitlab.com/cutecom/cutecom/). It is installable by

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cutecom
```

Then you have to open it and press *Settings* button to set the options:

[image: Cutecom]

hide settings by *^* button and finally open port by click on *Open* button.

Comment: In another system I do not have a serial port I am using socat to emulate that connection. In this system for CuteCom Device drop down showing empty. Any thoughts on how to show in the Device drop down